# Authentication with firestore in python using firebase_admin

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using firestore in python with firebase_admin and want to access the authentication module of firebase. I have created data in authentication with auth.create_user() by importing auth from firebase_admin.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore, auth

cred = credentials.Certificate("servicesAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

# <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<******************** SignUp ********************>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
def signUp(userObject):
     user = userObject.getUser()

     auth.create_user(uid=user['cnic'], email=user['email'], password=user['password'])     "
```

Now I want to authenticate for signIn but not able to find module auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password. This module is available with realtime database which connects with pyerbase but not in firestore connected with firebase_admin.

```
def signIn(cnic,password):
    auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(cnic, password)
```

I can use auth with pyrebase but i have to import pyrebase and firebase_admin both which i dont want it.
Is any module available for firebase_admin for authentication to signIN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Admin SDKs for Firebase run with elevated, administrative privileges, and don't have any capability to sign in a user.

You may want to consider your use-case: if you ship the administrative credentials (that the Admin SDK needs/uses) to your regular users they have full access to your Firebase and Google Cloud project. You'll want to separate the administrative functionality of your app from the end-user functionality, and use either the REST SDK or a client-side SDK (like Pyrebase) for the end-user app.